# Как в firebase обновить дочерний элемент?

Tags: javascript, firebase

использую firebase 9 Realtime Database
хочу обновить этот элемент ,но как до него добраться  если не знаю пути до него зарание , или ему надо поменять кеу на уникальный ? или добавить свойство кеу,но как потом найти его по этому свойству ?
я хочу узнать если метод поиска по базе без указания всей цепочке родителей ref.child('keep').child('sectionlist').child('1').child('itemlist').child('0')  по свойству или по ключу?
и может есть другой метод поиска,то тоже какой ? и как его использовать ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я помню, ID можно создавать самостоятельно, например UUID. Но для этого нужно настроить правила.

да id можно создавать самому но для этого надо узнать порядковый номер ,но это тоже не удобно так как при удалении элементов будет сбиваться и пока не знаю как узнать номер последнего в категории есть ли метод такой? Есть и авто генерация ,как в базе при добавлении новых элементов
я хочу узнать если метод поиска по базе без указания всей цепочке родителей? и может есть другой метод поиска,то тоже какой ? и как его использовать ?

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: да id можно создавать самому но для этого надо узнать порядковый номер ,но это тоже не удобно так как при удалении элементов будет сбиваться и пока не знаю как узнать номер последнего в категории есть ли метод такой? Есть и авто генерация ,как в базе при добавлении новых элементов я хочу узнать если метод поиска по базе без указания всей цепочке родителей? и может есть другой метод поиска,то тоже какой ? и как его использовать ?

Comment: push(child(ref(db), 'TaskLists')).key;
 добавляет такие ключи -MmSYhgp7Y7UY31Yg5H9